# What's options are there for localisation in WebWorks?

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-webworks

I'm building a WebWorks version of an Android app that's localised into 39 languages.

At the moment all the localisations are in xml files of key-value pairs, one file per language .
Each language file has about 400 lines (roughly 40k per file).

Users can change the language used in app.

**What options are there in WebWorks to solve this kind of situation?**

I'd be more than happy to convert the resource files into any other kind of format to make working with it a better experience on the platform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could store each language set in a JavaScript file that you include/load as needed. (I've converted the XML data to a "Map" since it is just key/value pairs)

e.g. (just ***ignore*** my translations... I just Googled this, I'm by no means fluent in Spanish)

```
//Spanish File "lang_spanish.js"
var translations = {
  "lose_a_turn":     "pierde un turno",
  "do_not_pass_go":  "huele como un camello",
  "take_a_card":     "tener una tarjeta de",
  "you_win_the_game":"sin motocicletas en la biblioteca",
  "you_can_not_move":"desbordamiento de la pila puede ser un lugar divertido"
};
```

In your `<head>` you can then have a generic script tag, that you just change the source of as needed.

e.g.

```
<script id="langFile" src="js/lang_english.js"></script>
```

When you want a different language, just remove this script from the DOM and add your new one. e.g.

```
function switchLang(langName){
    var headTag = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
    var scriptFile = document.getElementById('langFile');
    headTag.removeChild(scriptFile);
    var newScript = document.createElement('script');
      newScript.id = 'langFile';
      newScript.src = 'js/lang_' + langName + '.js';
    headTag.appendChild(newScript);
}
//call with:
switchLang('spanish');
```

The alternative would be to load all 39 languages by default... but that seems like overkill considering most will only ever want 1 or 2.

Comment: Thanks, this is actually very similar to what I went with.